# A Calculator program in C

Tags: c, calculator

I am trying to write a calculator program in C.

The input must be exactly in this form:

```
a oper b
```

where a, b are numbers of type double and oper is of these characters +,-,*,/ .

**Code:**

```
int main()
{
   char oper;
   double a, b;

   printf("What do you want to calculate?\n");
   if (scanf("%lf %1[-+/*] %lf", &a, &oper, &b) != 3)
        printf("Error. Invalid input.\n");
    else {

   switch(oper)
   {
    case '+':
        printf("%f+%f=%.2f",a,b,a+b);
        break;
    case '-':
        printf("%f-%f=%.2f",a,b,a-b);
        break;
    case '*':
        printf("%f*%f=%.2f",a,b,a*b);
        break;
    case '/':
        if(b != 0)
        {
                    printf("%f/%f=%.2f",a,b,a/b);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error! You can not divide by 0.");
            break;
        }
    default:
        printf("Error! Invalid operator.");
        break;
   }}
   return 0;
}
```

**Problem:**

*When user enters for example this input:*

```
123
```

*the program will just freeze.*

Meanwhile when user enters for example these inputs:

```
123 5
123 ab
Hello
```

our program will print

```
ERROR. Invalid input.
```

I really need your help. Would you please fix my code so that if we enter this input e.g.:

```
123
```

our program will print

```
ERROR. Invalid input.
```

Thaks

Comment: You also have a problem with `char oper; ... scanf("%lf %1[-+/*] %lf", &a, &oper, &b)`.  Change to `char oper[2]` and `scanf("%lf %1[-+/*] %lf", &a, oper, &b)`.

Answer (score 3):

Start with `fgets`:

```
char buffer[256];
printf("What do you want to calculate?\n");
fgets(buffer, 256, stdin);
if (sscanf(buffer, "%lf %1[-+/*] %lf", &a, &oper, &b) != 3)
    printf("Error. Invalid input.\n");
// .. rest of the code
```

Comment: Suggest change concerning `oper` as `%1[-+/*]` expects a string.

Answer (score 3):

Your program “freezes” on input `123` because `scanf` is not done reading when the user presses enter; it is expecting the operator and other operand to follow. You can enter those on subsequent lines. This is because any whitespace in the `scanf` formatter can stand for any amount and type of whitespace in the input, i.e., `123\n+\n\t   456` is valid and produces the same result as inputting `123+456`.

I would suggest reading one line at a time with `fgets` into a buffer, and the parsing it from there, e.g., with `sscanf`. If you wish to stick with just `scanf`, it is possible to make the format disallow newline separators, but then you *must* have whitespace between the operator and operands:

```
if (scanf("%lf%*[ \t]%1[-+/*]%*[ \t]%lf", &a, &oper, &b) != 3)
```

**edit**: Also, as pointed out by @chux, storing the result of `%1[-+/*]` in `char oper`  is incorrect, since the `%[]` formatter produces a string, which means that there must be room for the terminating NUL character. Either change the type to `char oper[2]` or the format to `%c`.

Comment: "must have whitespace between the operator and operands" is not quite right.  `"%lf"` and `" %lf"` behave the same.  Both will nicely consume a `\n` and then continue to scan a `double`.

Comment: @chux `%*[ \t]` will not match the empty string, and causes `scanf` to return in the OP's problem case of `123\n` input.

Comment: I see the error of my ways.  Forgot `%[]` does not match the empty string.

Comment: In any case the `fgets` solution is more robust and preferable, the `scanf` solution still has other problematic inputs such as `123 + \n`.

Answer (score 1):

On my test, the program isn't frozen when you enter "123", its just waiting for more input on the next line.  If you want to force it to get all its input from one line, the easiest way I know how it to read a string into memory, and then use sscanf() to scan the string.

So the top of the program would look like this:

```
int main()
{
    char line[100] ;
    char oper[4];
    double a, b;

    printf("What do you want to calculate?\n");
    if ( ! fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin))
        { printf("No input.\n") ;  exit( 1) ; }
    if (sscanf(line, "%lf %1[-+/*] %lf\n", &a, &oper, &b) != 3)
        printf("Error. Invalid input.\n");
    else {
        switch (* oper) {
```

Also, you may want to put a newline after your output.

Comment: Suggest change concerning `oper` as `%1[-+/*]` expects a string.

Comment: good call @chux.  It worked before, but probably only safe because of data type padding.  I don't tend to use scanf() for various reasons, including this possibility of buffer overflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<Stdio.h>
int main()
{
 double a,b;
 char operator;
 puts("Please enter your two operands");
 printf("operand no 1 = ");
 scanf("%f",&a);
 printf("operand no 2 = ");
 scanf("%f",&b);
 puts("Now choose what do you want to calculate");
 printf("+ - * / which one : ");
 scanf("%c",operator);
 if(operator=='+')
   printf("ans = %f ",a+b);
 else if(operator=='-')
   printf("ans = %f ",a-b);
 elseif(operator=='*')
   printf("ans = %f ",a*b);
 else if(operator=='/')
   printf("ans = %f ",a/b);
 puts("thank you !");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: simple calculator for beginners